# Create list of nodes that are referenced at least once

Tags: drupal, view, arguments, relationships, panels

I'm sure this is simple with the Node Relationship module but I can't wrap my head around it.

I have a list called 'Comedian Profile' which has a node reference field for it. You then make - you guess it - profiles for comedians. To make an 'Events' (that doubles as an Ubercart item) you select the comedian. It then creates a view in the profile that lists all of that person's upcoming events.

Now what I need is an listing that shows in order of the date field each comedians name that is referenced(I'll worry about the other fields later). Note that the name is the referenced term.

Is this the right approach? If so could someone point me in the right direction or suggest a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got it right, you can accomplish this using views relationships.

Add the field "Comedian" of the Event content type as a Relationship in the view (be sure to check the "Require this relationship" box). Then, add the fields, selecting the relationship you created. If the "Comedian" field is optional, check the "Hide if empty" box.